# vb6 call form with name contained in array

Tags: vb6, dynamic-forms

I have an Array named Menus. It contains a form name per element.

How can I call them dynamically?

For example, if **Menus(1) = "Login"**, and **Menus(2) = "Logout"** I need to say

```
Login.Show
```

but I want to do this using the Array name. I clearly can't do this:

```
Menus(X).Show
```

Is this possible in VB or is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're essentially trying to do is use a form's name to instantiate and load a form.

One way to do this is to pass a string with your form's name to the Form `Collection`'s `Add` function:

```
Dim f As Form
Set f = Forms.Add(Menus(X))
f.Show
```

Or, using VB6's [CallByName](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186143) Function:

```
Dim f As Form
Set f = CallByName(Forms, "Add", VbMethod, Menus(X))
f.Show
```

Comment: Cool! That did the trick. I used the first method. +1 for your alternatives :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
Form form = Menus[x] as Form 
Form.show
```

Comment: Of course, that code doesn't even compile, so it's not a particularly good "example"...

Comment: What's with the first line? I don't recognize this as VB syntax.