# VB6 and VBScript Dynamic Form Loading

Tags: winforms, vbscript, vb6, scriptcontrol

I have a list of strings that represent existing form names in my vb6 project. I need to iterate through each name and dynamically load each form to access its controls programmatically. So far I have tried using the ScriptHost command to execute a string generated script however, I have not been successful in loading the form.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [VB6 - Show forms by passing form name as string](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?389919-VB6-Show-forms-by-passing-form-name-as-string). Also this [vb6 call form with name contained in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692147/vb6-call-form-with-name-contained-in-array)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add forms using your names, then show.

```
Set frm = Forms.Add("myForm")
frm.Show()
```